# MAMP Drupal 6 White Page Problem

Tags: drupal, mamp

I've been trying to install an existing drupal 6 app into a MAMP environment (mac), but i get a white page as a result of the home page. The thing is that i can access to the rest of pages if i put the absolute url, but it doesn't show anything at root ( http://virtualhostname/ )! Maybe it's a question of the .htaccess and rewrite issues. I already setted up the memory_limit of php.ini of mamp and drupal to 256M so i don't think this is the problem either. Maybe is the db, cause some parts of the pages doesn't show properly, maybe at the import something went wrong, i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably a php problem. Check your apache logs for the error. If you are running linux, just go to the terminal and do 'tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log' and referesh the url you are getting the white page.

This will let you know the reason for the white page and then you can resolve it. You can paste the error over here, so that people can look and help you debugging it.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines at the top of your index.php file, it will display the error out to the screen instead of just the white page.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

**UPDATE**

Sounds like the 'whitespace at the end of template files' problem, details and fixes are here: http://drupal.org/node/1424

Comment: this is good advice for a test site, but in a live web environment it's better to have a white screen than expose your error messages to the end user. On a live site, you should look at the server error log to see the PHP errors rather than displaying them on the page.

Comment: +1 Definitely, I thought since the OP was using MAMP this would likely be a development site. I hope no-one rolls live sites using MAMP!!

Comment: Yes, is a dev environment. I tried with the code above and this is what i get: 
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent  AND Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: Ah, this sounds like the old whitespace at the end of template.php problem - see [this link](http://drupal.org/node/1424) for a fix. Read the page carefully all the way down to the comment at the bottom

Comment: So thanks to all of you, the problem seemed to be that i had to run the update.php script! now, things are showed better, tough not perfect. Thanks for your help it aided me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a php memory issue, but I have also seen similar situations where having an OP code cache like APC gets messed up and the usual solution is to restart apache to solve it.

Make sure you clear cache and run update.php

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was simply that... the code was corrupted! jesus.